# Setter and Getter conventions

Tags: private, setter, public, conventions, getter

```
public class Score {

    private String score;


    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

Working on a project, in which I found this piece of code

The funcitionality of this piece of code is easy, nevertheless I cannot understand why to make the String score private if the setter is public. To me this looks like the sense of making score private is broken by a public setter.

Thank you in advance to help me evolving from newbie to at least a bit of a programmer.

Comment: The whole point of distinguishing public and private in OO programming is so that you can separate _what_ the class does from _how_ it does it. Setters and getters are abstract, variables are concrete.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight it does look like broken encapsulation. However there are two advantages in the above.

1. Implementation. The implementation *doesn't* have to be a `String` variable. The setter implementation could write it to a database, and the getter retrieves it.
2. Validation. Just exposing the field means you could set the `String` to whatever you want. By introducing a setter method you allow for checks for (say) length, nulls, content etc.

The above means you can implement the class how you want and in a manner distinct from the interface (imagine - you could abstract those methods into an interface and provide *multiple* implementations all operating in profounding different ways). Because they adhere to the same interface you can substitute one implementation for another with no changes to the surrounding code.

I would say (further to this) that I tend not to like the above pattern. My reasoning is that advantage of OO is that you can tell objects to do things on your behalf, *not* so that you can extract the fields yourself and perform your own logic using them. Because of that I tend to be suspicious of classes consiting of fields together with setters/getters.

Comment: Thx for the answer, this one helped me most. Still I cannot recommend as my reputation is still low :(

Answer (score 0):

Getters and setters are used, because if you decide half way through your project to change the way that your variable works, or if you want to modify the value from the original, you would have to go through your code and change all calls to that public variable.

However, with getters and setters, you can just change how the variable is handled inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

1. `private` keyword means that the attribute or method declared as so
   is only visible inside your class.
2. `public` keyword means that the attribute or method declared as so is visible to anyone.

This practices is well known as encapsulation of information. The public setters and getters allow the programmer to control what the user of these functions can do to your private attributes.